# htaccess запретить воспроизведение mp3 на других сайтах

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть на сайте ссылка такого вида: site/path/mymusic.mp3. Другие сайты использует с моего воспроизведение по этой ссылке. Как разрешить воспроизведение .mp3 только на моем домене?

Comment: В общем никак, и `.htaccess` тут не поможет

Comment: Вообще вариантов нет? Возможно без .htaccess как-то можно?

Comment: Можно только усложнить получение прямой ссылки (различными способами), но запретить ее использовать вы никак не сможете.

Comment: 100% рабочих способов особо нет, но можете попытаться повлиять на это с помощью пары уловок: бан по IP (не спасёт, если запрашивается с клиентской стороны, например, с браузера), CORS (для клиентской стороны запрет по хедеру Origin, но опять таки зависит следует ли браузер политике CORS) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: А запрет хотлинков больше не работает? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA

Comment: Пробивной способ есть, если хранить куки. Суть - запрет на доступ при отсутствии куки, которая ставится при посещении страницы сайта. Сторонний сайт может иметь прямую ссылку, но вот поставить куку он не сможет. Единственный способ обойти это ограничение - посетитель уже должен побывать на вашем сайте. Либо сторонний сервер должен использовать прокси, который "добавит" эту куку. Если будет интерес, выложу конфиги веб-сервера.